# What to add to CSS to make the sidemenu wider?

Tags: html, css

The sidemenu is on the right side of the display, and should be 25% of the display, but the menu does not fill it out completely. The size is relate to its longest element (in this case the TÁMOP...). I set the width to 100% but it does not work. How do I make it to fill it out completely? I would use % not px if it is possible.

```css
/*Set the parent <li>’s CSS position property to ‘relative’.*/

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
 float: right;
}
ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -200px;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
li ul {
 margin-top: -50px;
 display:none;
}
ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
.main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
ul ul ul {
 margin-left: -120px;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>oldal.menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                href="side.menu2.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Közérdekű adatok</a></li>
                <li><a>Járóbeteg szakellátó</a></li>
                <li><a>Álláslehetőségek</a></li>
                <li><a>Közszolgálati intézmények</a></li>
                <li><a>Civil szervezetek</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a>Egyházak</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Református egyház</a></li>
                        <li><a>Katolikus egyház</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Idegenforgalom</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Térkép</a></li>
                        <li><a>Vadászat</a></li>
                        <li><a>Horgászat</a></li>
                        <li><a>Túrázás</a></li>
                        <li><a>Szálláslehetőségek</a></li>
                        <li><a>Kultúrális rendezvények</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Galéria</a></li>
                <li><a>Kiadványok</a></li>
                <li><a>Cigándi hírmondó</a></li>
                <li><a>Árapasztó tározó</a></li>
                <li><a>Gazdahírek</a></li>
                <li><a>Archívum</a></li>
                <li><a>Eladó ingatlanok</a></li>
                <li><a>Hasznos linkek</a></li>
                <li><a>Kistérség</a></li>
                <li><a>Magyar Államkincstár</a></li>
                <li><a>TÁMOP-3.2.3/A-11/1-2012-0112</a></li>
                <li><a>Cigándi Járási Hivatal</a></li>
                <li><a>ITS projekt</a></li>
                <li><a>Település üzemeltetés</a></li>
                <li><a>Művészeti csoportok</a></li>
                <li><a>ÁNYK nyomtatványok</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the code provided the side menu is not declared as `width: 25%`. Please provide a full working esample.

Comment: @Zoltán Fodor Nem igazán értem mi a gond, leírnád magyarul hogy mi nem működik?

Comment: Szóval van a .rightcolumn class ami 25%-ra van beállítva. Ebbe a class-ba akarom tenni a #menu -t. De a #menu nem veszi fel mind a 25% helyet, mint az alatta lévő .card class. A #menu szélessége a karakterekhez igazodik ami jelen esetben a leghosszabb gomb a "TÁMOP-3.2.3/A-11/1-2012-0112". Én ennél szélesebb #menu-t akarok, hogy igazodjon a szélessége a .card class-hoz.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<head>
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 5%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
/* Left column */
.leftcolumn {   
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

/* Right column */
.rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

/* Fake image */
.fakeimg {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
}

/* Add a card effect for articles */
.card {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
    .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
/*slideshow*/
header.mySlides {display:none;}


/*Set the parent <li>’s CSS position property to ‘relative’.*/

#main-navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
#main-navigation ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
#main-navigation li ul {
 display:none;
}
#main-navigation ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
#main-navigation ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
#main-navigation li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
#main-navigation li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
 #main-navigation li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
#main-navigation li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
.main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

#main-navigation {
 width: 100%;
}
/*Start menu*/
#menu {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0.6em;
}
#menu ul:before,
#menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
/*Set the parent <li>’s CSS position property to ‘relative’.*/

#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
 float: right;
}
#menu ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -18em;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
#menu li ul {
 margin-top: -50px;
 display:none;
}
#menu ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
#menu li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
#menu li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
#menu li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
 #menu li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
.main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
#menu ul ul ul {
 margin-left: -120px;
 top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
 <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="width: 100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="cigand1.jpg" style="width:25%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="eu1.jpeg" style="width:25%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="hun1.jpg" style="width:25%">
</div>
</div>

<div id="main-navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a>Városunk</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Köszöntő</a></li>
     <li><a>Földrajz</a></li>
     <li><a>Története</a></li>
     <li><a>Heraldika</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Önkormányzat</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Polgármesteri Hivatal</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Polgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Alpolgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Jegyző</a></li>
       <li><a>Titkárság</a></li>
       <li><a>Hatósági és Igazgatási Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Építésügyi és Városfejlesztési Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Pénzügyi Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Letölthető dokumentumok</a></li>
       <li><a>Pályázatok</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>EU</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP</a></li>
         <li><a>TIOP-1.2.3</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.1.0/A/11.</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0121</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0124</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-4.2.0/A/11-2011-0626</a></li>
         <li><a>EOP-5.5.0/K/14-2014-0031</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP-1.A.3-2014-2014-0116</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-5.7.0/15-2015-0275</a></li>
         <li><a>KÖFOP-1.2.1-VEKOP-16-2016-00280</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Képviselő-testület</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Képviselők</a></li>
       <li><a>Határozatok, Rendeletek</a></li>
       <li><a>Rendelet-tervezetek</a></li>
       <li><a>estületi ülések</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>RNÖ</a></li>
     <li><a>Telefonszámok</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Oktatás és Kultúra</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Oktatás</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Cigánd</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Óvoda</a></li>
         <li><a>Iskola</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Révleányvár</a></li>
       <li><a>Zemplénagárd</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Kultúra</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Művelődési Ház</a></li>
       <li><a>Városi Könyvtár</a></li>
       <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Iskolakonyha</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Egészségügy</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Háziorvosok</a></li>
     <li><a>Fogorvos</a></li>
     <li><a>Központi Orvosi Ügyelet</a></li>
     <li><a>Védőnői Szolgálat</a></li>
     <li><a>Járóbeteg Szakrendelő</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Hagyományok</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
     <li><a>Tájház</a></li>
     <li><a>Óvodamúzeum</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Sport</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Intézmények</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Szabadidő Központ</a></li>
       <li><a>Műfüves-pálya</a></li>
       <li><a>Labdarúgó-pálya</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Cigánd SE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Kezdőlap</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
  <div id="menu">
      <ul>
    <li><a>Közérdekű adatok</a></li>
    <li><a>Járóbeteg szakellátó</a></li>
    <li><a>Álláslehetőségek</a></li>
    <li><a>Közszolgálati intézmények</a></li>
    <li><a>Civil szervezetek</a></li>
    <li><a>Egyházak</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Református egyház</a></li>
      <li><a>Katolikus egyház</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Idegenforgalom</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Térkép</a></li>
      <li><a>Vadászat</a></li>
      <li><a>Horgászat</a></li>
      <li><a>Túrázás</a></li>
      <li><a>Szálláslehetőségek</a></li>
      <li><a>Kultúrális rendezvények</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Galéria</a></li>
    <li><a>Kiadványok</a></li>
    <li><a>Cigándi hírmondó</a></li>
    <li><a>Árapasztó tározó</a></li>
    <li><a>Gazdahírek</a></li>
    <li><a>Archívum</a></li>
    <li><a>Eladó ingatlanok</a></li>
    <li><a>Hasznos linkek</a></li>
    <li><a>Kistérség</a></li>
    <li><a>Magyar Államkincstár</a></li>
    <li><a>TÁMOP-3.2.3/A-11/1-2012-0112</a></li>
    <li><a>Cigándi Járási Hivatal</a></li>
    <li><a>ITS projekt</a></li>
    <li><a>Település üzemeltetés</a></li>
    <li><a>Művészeti csoportok</a></li>
    <li><a>ÁNYK nyomtatványok</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
      <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
      <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
      <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Me</h3>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
 <script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add some css .   #menu > ul{ width:100%;}
 #menu > ul > li{ margin-left:0}  
 #menu > ul > li li{ left:-180px;}